# How to keep terminal for installation of debugging symbols of apport's local investigation alive?

Tags: command-line, apt, gnome-terminal, apport

`apport` allows to investigate crashes locally and to either start a `gdb` session, get a backtrace or install debugging symbols in that local investigation. When choosing the latter a `gnome-terminal` is displayed to monitor the progress of updating the `apt` sources and installing the `-dbg` packages. How can I keep that terminal window from disappearing if the `apt-get` process finished or crashed?

The solution shouldn't require any interaction with the terminal at all after the installation has been started.

This is crucial for debugging failures of `apport` itself. Currently the terminal disappears without any noticeable error and then an `apport` dialog for the package which didn't finish to create the backtrace or for the crash of `apport` itself (starting an infinite loop of `apport` detecting its own crash) is opened.

Note: This in not about a specific issue that makes the `gnome-terminal` opened by `apport` disappear, i.e. I don't care if apt-get makes a segmentation fault or a dpkg subroutine returns != 0, ...

Comment: Tried opening a second tab in it?

Comment: The tab is closed then and the second becomes the only one. Your comment lead me to exclude solutions which require any interaction.

Comment: Do I understand right: you call `apport in gnome-terminal` and then it crashes ? or do you call it some other way ?

Comment: Regardless of where I invoke `apport` (`gnome-terminal`, `xterm` or KDE `konsole`) `apport` itselfs opens a `gnome-terminal` which crashes/disappears.

Comment: Here's a thought: Change the ownership of the running process to root. `apport` should be unable to kill it, but might crash when it notices it failed to do so.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3512861/2032568) can give you some other ideas...

Comment: @Alex it would if I was opening the `gnome-terminal`, but `apport` does programmatically and this step needs to be configured/made configurable in order to apply solutions in the link you posted.

Comment: @Alex regarding the process ownership change: That violates my requirement for the solution to not require any interaction at all

Comment: @KarlRichter you could script it I guess.

Comment: @Alex Agreed. I guess it's easier to make a feature-request and control the opening of the `gnome-terminal` within the `apport` configuration.

Comment: Silly question, but isn't the following keeping the terminal window open: from the Gnome-terminal menu Edit  > Profile Preferences > Title and command (tab) > "When command exits" (drop down menu) > "Hold the terminal open"?

Comment: @JacobVlijm Might, but that requires to change the settings for `gnome-terminal` and affects all usage of it (it's no longer possible to close it with Ctrl+D and `exit` which is too annoying...)

Comment: True, but you could probably script it to *temporarily* change the setting during running the session and switch back afterwards automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't seem to exist and there's no need to figure out nasty workarounds. I opened [feature request/bug 1442159](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apport/+bug/1442159) to get developer feedback.

Comment: This would appear to be a feature request, not a bug.

Comment: @ElderGeek I guess in strict launchpad language there're only bugs and bugs on the wishlist.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised to see it converted to a question.  Like this one: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apport/+question/40131

Answer (score 1):

Since apport supports interactive feedback as discussed at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Apport/DeveloperHowTo#Custom_Invocation it would seem all that's required is to start the process with a variant on the

Yes/No Question psuedo code

def add_info(report, ui):

```
close_terminal = False

if ui and ui.yesno('Close Terminal?') == True:
    close_terminal = True

if close_terminal == True:
    # user wants terminal to close
```

Note: I'm not a developer so don't hold my feet to the fire, but logically this seems like something the devs could do without much difficulty.

Comment: Linked in the feature request on launchpad.